# Need help fixing an IF(AND statement in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am a beginner at using Excel and I've been trying to code a particular condition. The condition is as follows,

```
If A<75 and B<75 then do nothing
If A>75 and B<75 then A-75
If A<75 and B>75 then B-75
If A>75 and B>75 then (A-75)+(B-75)
```

Here, A and B are numerical values in two different cells.
So I wrote a formula and it works when the IF statements are not nested. However when I combine the formula it gives me an error. The formula I wrote is as follows.

```
=IF(AND(S180<75,V180<75),0,"-",IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,"-",IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,"-",IF(AND(S180>75,V180>75),(S180-75)+(V180-75),"-"))))
```

The formulae that work are as follows,

```
=IF(AND(S180<75,V180<75),0,"-") 
=IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,"-") 
=IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,"-") 
=IF(AND(S180>75,V180>75),(S180-75)+(V180-75),"B")
```

I want the conditions to all be applied in a single cell so that I can switch the resulting value into standard values from another table using the =switch function. I am using Excel Online. Any help fixing my formula is welcome.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You are not nesting IF conditions properly , to nest IF you need to include another IF in the FALSE condition of the first IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IF, but could be shortened:

```
=IF(AND(S180>75,V180>75),S180+V180-150,IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,IF(AND(S180<76,V180>75),V180-75,IF(AND(S180<75,V180<75),""))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Going to use this to shorten other IF statements as well!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a recent version of Excel with the [IFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)?

```
=ifs(AND(S180<75, V180<75), 0, AND(S180>75, V180<75), S180-75, AND(S180>75, V180<75), S180-75, AND(S180>75, V180>75), (S180-75)+(V180-75), TRUE, "B")
```

If you try this formula and end up with a #NAME? error then your version does not support IFS.

Comment: My version does support the ifs function! Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this nested IF ,

To nest IF you need to include another IF in the FALSE condition of the first IF

> =IF(AND(S180<75,V180<75),0,IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,IF(AND(S180>75,V180<75),S180-75,IF(AND(S180>75,V180>75),(S180-75)+(V180-75),"-"))))

Comment: What about if more than one false condition needs to be applied?

Comment: What you mean by more than one false condition ,as per your first example you only have four conditions ? Can you be bit more specific.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not understand your answer. Can you explain what you mean by "including another IF in the false condition of the first IF"?

Comment: To understand this write a simple IF statement e.g. IF(Condition , true , false) , now in this if you want to add another condition you'd have to write IF(Condition , true , IF(condition, true,false)) ...